# Highlight modified fields in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

I have a complex UI that renders multiple `<lightning-input>` fields. When the user edits these fields, I store the `originalValue` (usually passed through an `@api` property), the `newValue` and the `oldValue`. This allows me to easily identify, if a particular field has been modified (e.g. current value is different from the original value).

Now I want to highlight those fields, for example to display a light-yellow background as long as they are modified.

I tried modifying the triggering element via `event.currentTarget` with standard HTML ([W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)):

```js
// testComponent.js
handleChange(event) {
    this.newRecord['myField'] = event.detail.value;
    if (this.isModified('myField')) event.currentTarget.classList.add('dirty-field');
    if (!this.isModified('myField')) event.currentTarget.classList.remove('dirty-field');
    }

isModified(fieldName) {
    return this.newRecord[fieldName] !== this.originalRecord[fieldName];
}
```

```css
/* testComponent.css */
.dirty-field {
    border: solid orange 1px;
}
```

```html
<!-- testComponent.html -->
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal_medium">
            <lightning-input
                label="Test Input"
                value={originalRecord.myField}
                onchange={handleChange}
                variant="label-inline">
            </lightning-input>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

This code at least allows me to display an orange border around the whole input field.

I understand the concept of shadow DOM; I know that I can not modify the underlying `<input>` field from the `<lightning-input>` with a `querySelector`.

Is there any way to highlight a field as "modified" (how salesforce does it with their datatable, for example)? Or, more generally speaking: to modify the appearance of the input-boxes from an input field?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but just wanted to chime in here because we are doing this exact thing with a complex form where we want to highlight changes. The Shadow DOM definitely prevents you from giving it custom styling in the traditional sense but you can get around that with design tokens.

In our Javascript file we define a getter that allows us to apply custom styling via a class name only if the input we're looking at has a different value than the original.

```js
get customLabelStyling() { return this.labelIsChanged ? 'custom-input--changed' : ''; }
```

Then in our CSS file we define a styling that uses the pseudo style `:host` which scopes our style to the Shadow DOM. We can then more specifically target our specific input we want to alter by giving it the class we're looking for. Once we have that we can override the design tokens/[styling hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/) that the default lightning-input component uses for its border and shadow box in both unfocused and focused states. Then we give it the colors and styling we want. For ours we chose an orangish yellow to indicate a change has happened.

```css
:host .custom-input--changed {
    --slds-c-input-color-border: rgb(253 175 25);
    --slds-c-input-shadow: rgb(231 223 54) 0 0 0 1px inset;
    --slds-c-input-color-border-focus: rgb(253 175 25);
    --slds-c-input-shadow-focus: rgb(231 223 54) 0 0 0 1px inset;
}
```

Finally just make sure in your HTML file that your lightning-input has its style set to the dynamic style getter from our Javascript file like this,

```html
<lightning-input 
    type="text" 
    label="Custom Label"
    class={customLabelStyling}
    value={pendingCustomLabel} 
    onchange={handleLabelChange}>
</lightning-input>
```

And there you have it. We're now interacting with styling in the Shadow DOM. If I ever need to dive into styling on a component I can't typically access through the Shadow DOM like this, I'll inspect my source and see what design tokens are being applied to it and see if I can follow a similar pattern to alter its design tokens.